# Delete a sublist from the list of list, based on value of a specific element from the sublist

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists which has Sell and Bid input as sublists from an Auction Site. I need to compare the closing timestamp of the Sell sublist list and if any bid sublist has greater bid timestamp than the  closing timestamp, I need to ignore or delete that submission.

So far, I have the closing sublist timestamp, I can do a comparison to find the list that has a higher bid timestamp, but I am not able to delete it. When I use `.pop`, it still does not delete. Can you please let me know how to delete the entire list if its timestamp is greater than the closing timestamp?

In the below input, the last value '20' in the First list is the closing Time.
The 4th list has a starting timestamp of 21, so I need to delete it.

My list:

```
['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20']
['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00']
['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00']
['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']
```

My Code

```
for each_entry in each_bid_item:
        initial_time = (each_entry[0][0])
        close_time = (each_entry[0][5])
        reserve_price = (each_entry[0][4])
        display_item = (each_entry[0][3])

    for entry in each_entry:
        if entry[0] > close_time:
            entry.pop
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. Please edit the post to show your correct code. Also, when you use a function, you need to put `()` after it to call, so `entry.pop()`. `entry.pop` is a noop.

Comment: What makes `20` ther closing time? I mean, you have one list with five elements and a couple of lists with four elements - what is the logic here?

Comment: entry.pop() just drops the element rather than dropping the entire sublist.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of filter here, or use a list comprehension. Try something like this:

```py
lst = [['15', '8', 'SELL', 'tv_1', '250.00', '20'],
['18', '1', 'BID', 'tv_1', '150.00'],
['19', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '200.00'],
['21', '3', 'BID', 'tv_1', '300.00']]

# Filter:
lst = list(filter(lambda l: int(l[0]) <= 20, lst))
# List comprehension:
lst = [entry for entry in lst if int(entry[0]) <= 20]
```

Comment: hi, thank you. If I run the code in a separate window, it works, but this is inside a for loop in my code, and it does not work unfortunately. Does keeping this code inside For loop make any difference?

Comment: @user6662097 please provide more information about the data structures that you are using. What for loop do you have? This replaces the need of your for loops in your OP question

Answer (score 0):

`entry.pop` returns the actual function, instead of calling it. You need to call it with `entry.pop()`.

Comment: hi Algebra8, entry.pop() just drops the element rather than dropping the entire sublist.

Comment: @user6662097 might want to try `each_entry.pop()` to drop the whole sublist, but you'll more likely want `each_entry.remove(entry)`. Although anything like this in a for each loop will have logic being messed up

Comment: @user6662097 I think one of the issues is that I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. For example, this line: `I need to compare the closing timestamp of the Sell sublist list and if any bid sublist has greater bid timestamp than the closing timestamp, I need to ignore or delete that submission.` suggests a `list` of lists might not be the best idea. Maybe look into `dict`s?